# How do I make an exact back up of one iPod Touch to another iPod Touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod

I want both iPods to be identical- including the folders and organization I have already made on the first iPod.

Answer (score 1):

Sync the iPod so it creates a backup of it. Take the 2nd iPod and restore it. When you finish the restore and it begins the setup on iTunes, select that it restores as a backup of the first iPod that you just synced. From then on out you can just sync each iPod every time you add new music, etc.